# Listing file in location

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm a little stuck, as for this moment i don't have any code only an idea.

I was thinking to make a program in asp.net to list files within a location.
The file will probably be releases for programs and mods for gaming and stuff.

But i have searched everywhere to get files in a location. I could use system.io.fileinfo to list files in a directory.
But how to I get a Directory not in the solution but somehwere on the hard drive or even external storage server? The location i prefer not to be hard coded but selected by the user? any toughts on how a user can select a 'location' ?

Comment: You cannot access the client's file system from the server, if that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: There are multiple unanswered questions here. What do you mean by external storage? Is it some storage on cloud? Directory on client machine? Does the web application have proper access rights to list the files from that storage?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? Your not trying to do this from a website are you?

Comment: yes that's the hole point from a website. sorry difficult to explain. i mean by external storage a folder location on a server, vm or storage server doesn't matter. For instance i want to list releases probably zip files. all those zip files are in a folder of location for example c:\releases. the idea is to specify this location in an administrator account not user account of course. The question to it is do i need to insert the exact location or am i able to select the location. Like in winforms you can use a folderbrowserdialog for it. is there such a possibility in asp web apps too?

Answer (score 0):

In a console application, you could be doing something like this :

- Ask for the path from the user with a readline.
- Check if the path is correct / exists. (if not you could create it or display an error, also it could be a path with a file, you need to check if the path is to a directory or to a file)
- Do the display of the files inside of the directory as intended.

We need more precisions if you want a better answer.